# Counting words and sum digits why doesnt it work?

Tags: c#

Task:
The program asks the user to enter the text, after entering the text, the program declares how many words are in the text. It also counts the amount of digits in the text and displays it on the screen.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Insert text: ");

        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int count = 1, num, sum = 0, r;
        for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i]))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (num != 0)
        {
            r = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : " + sum);
        Console.WriteLine("In text {1} names", s, count);

    }
```

The program asks for the text and numbers to be entered. The numbers in the text are counted why doesnt it work correctly?

Comment: Can you be more specific what "does not work correctly"? What is the expected output vs the actual output. Is the result off-by-one? Is the result missing? Does the program crash under certain conditions?

Comment: for example Input: xsad8 dlas8 dsao9 and the Output: sum 25

Comment: I cannot input the text in one command line, it automatically switches to second command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the input/output described in the comment, You do not need a second ReadLine Statement. You can do as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Text");
    var userEntry = Console.ReadLine();
    var countOfWords = userEntry.Split(new []{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
    var sum = userEntry.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).Select(x=>int.Parse(x.ToString())).Sum();
    Console.WriteLine($"Count Of Words :{countOfWords}{Environment.NewLine}Sum :{sum}");
}
```

This is in the case when(as per your comment), the input string is "xsad8 dlas8 dsao9", for which the sum would be 25.

If the input string is "xsad8 dlas81 dsao9" and you want to treat 81 as '81', rather than 8 & 1, the Sum can be calculated as follows.

```
var sum = Regex.Split(userEntry, @"\D+").Where(s => s != String.Empty).Sum(x=>int.Parse(x));
```

Sum in above case would be 98

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I hope it will help you.

```
using System;

namespace SimpleProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Task:
            // The program asks the user to enter the text, after 
            // entering the text, the program declares how many words
            // are in the text. It also counts the amount of digits in 
            // the text and displays it on the screen.

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Text");
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            int wordCount = 0;

            char[] wordsArray = word.ToCharArray();
            foreach (var item in wordsArray)
            {
                //Counting the number of words in array.
                wordCount = wordCount + 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Entered Text: " + word);
            Console.WriteLine("No. of Counts: " + wordCount);

        }
    }
}
```